# Locating VS Code's stored environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

Where does Visual Studio Code store the environment variables and connection details for extensions, such as the Snowflake database extension, on my local machine?

I have a lot of DB and I want to find the file that contains their names and passwords and transfer it to other users in the team without them having to enter the names and passwords again.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Environment variables are not stored anywhere. And every extension can handle this in its own way, though usually extension settings are part of your user/workspace settings, which are stored as json files. If not, check the documentation of the particular extension you are using.

Comment: can you give some specific examples of environment variables you are curious about?